# Compare letters from images for recognition (opencv, java)

Tags: java, opencv

I have been working with this project lately in order to detect letters and im a little bit stuck right now.

So far I have been able to extract all letters and crop them and save them to new images. Now I would like to compare letters for recognition. Lets say that i have saved all letters already that I am using as a reference or template in order to detect a match between letters.

How can I with good result compare for example the letter A with the letters Å,Ä,A and tell that A is the match?

letter A
[image]
letter Ä
[image]
letter Å
[image]

I have tried with matchTemplate but i do not really understand it. Like this but i dont know how to continue..

```
     Mat img = Highgui.imread("image.jpg");
     Mat templ = Highgui.imread("aaa.jpg");                 

     int result_cols = img.cols() - templ.cols() + 1;
     int result_rows = img.rows() - templ.rows() + 1;
     Mat result = new Mat(result_rows, result_cols, CvType.CV_32FC1);

     Imgproc.matchTemplate(img, templ, result, 1);
```

I could of course use Tesseract, but I would like to recognize letters in opencv as the letters will always look the same and not change font or something like that. So there is no need for an OCR engine.

Comment: You don't want to use neural networks ?.If you wish , then go through this link http://www.heatonresearch.com/articles/7

Comment: Well no not really. I would like to use opencv functions. Thanks anyway